Unable to remove/hide the Cookie from request header in an Angular application with nginx reverse proxy
I am using nginx reverse proxy server to run my Angular application, in my application I am fetching data from Elasticsearch, while fetching via REST APIs it throws too long frame exception: HTTP header is greater than 8K bytes. In order to fix the issue I tried to remove the 'Cookie' attribute from http header via the nginx.conf file, but did not work, have added below the nginx props used in nginx.conf file.
proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
proxy_set_header Cookie "";

This is an intermittent issue, clearing the browser cache resolves the issue temporarily but is reproducible again. Please suggest what should be the approach here.
